# Do concepts of nat bar nat and batel beshishim apply to ovens?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bitul-batel-null

In a prior post I asked about batel beshishim and [nat bar nat](https://thoughtsfromtheshteiblech.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/nat-bar-nat-part-1/) (*noten ta'am bar noten ta'am*) as it applies to pots and utensils.  Do these concepts apply to ovens?  If yes why?  If not, why?

If these concepts do apply, I can see it going both ways.  One the one hand, there would seem to be even less "particles" from the surrounding oven making their way into the food, as the food is not touching the oven directly, unlike with pots and pans.  On the other hand, there is steam.  I am aware as well of differences between vented and non-vented ovens.  But I suspect there are a completely different set of issues regarding ovens and the above analysis might not at all be relevant.

Would greatly appreciate if someone could tie this all together for me.

Comment: The question with ovens is does steam make the food as if it's touching the walls. If yes, then the oven is just like a pot. If no, then there's no need for Nat bar Nat or bittul anyway.

Comment: Nat bar Nat for Rican is without bowling pot. Nat bar Nat is step by step

Comment: https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/3704/oven-kashrus-101-using-the-same-oven-for-meat-dairy-fish-pareve/